# md-autocomplete validation issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

We have a md-autocomplete directive with required atribute. Expected behavior is to ng-message be hidden when user enters to form view, then if click submit button and autocomplete is empty or if start typing on it and leaves it blank show the validation error.

The validation works fine but when user chooses a suggestion from autocomplete, validation error shows momentarily and hides as you can see in gif.

[image: Validation error flicks]

Using angular-material 1.0.9.

Code of md-autocomplete:

```
<md-autocomplete
  flex
  required
  id="name"
  md-input-name="name"
  md-search-text="ctrl.searchCustomer"
  md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedCustomerChange(item)"
  md-items="item in ctrl.queryCustomer(ctrl.searchCustomer)"
  md-item-text="item.display"
  md-min-length="0"
  md-floating-label="{{'Customer' | translate}}">

    <md-item-template>
        <span 
          md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchCustomer"
          md-highlight-flags="^i">
            {{item.display}}
        </span>
    </md-item-template>
    <div 
      ng-show="ctrl.forms.profileForm.name.$error && ctrl.forms.profileForm.name.$touched"
      ng-messages="ctrl.forms.profileForm.name.$error">
        <div ng-messages-include="components/global/error-list.html">
        </div>
    </div>
 </md-autocomplete>
```

Is there a way to avoid this issue?